# How to specify different token_policies and specify lease duration from user input in hashicorp vault?

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

On authenitcation ldap client I got a client login response something like this:

```
{
    u'lease_id': u'',
    u'warnings': None,
    u'wrap_info': None,
    u'auth': {
        u'token_policies': 
            [u'default', u'example'], 
        u'orphan': True,
        u'entity_id': u'4034de6b-3ea8-afea-94d8-3052ef24f528', 
        u'token_type': u'service',
        u'lease_duration': 2764800, 
        u'policies': 
            [u'default', u'example'], 
        u'client_token': u's.qguG0Wo29vc1nYO2SqLcrMri',
        u'accessor': u'm8oU8sKsRjYxeX39hx2UFEso',
        u'renewable': True,
        u'metadata': 
            {u'username': u'ciasto'}
            },
     u'lease_duration': 0, 
     u'request_id': u'96676543-5a59-cdff-4199-b75492858af', 
     u'data': {},
     u'renewable': False
}
```

How can I specify different token policy ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont control what policies you get when you login, Vault does.

Your options would be to modify that group mapping, more info [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/ldap#ldap-group-policy-mapping)
or create a subsequent token if you are allowed by calling this command

```
vault token create -policy example
```

Comment: Do you mean when we login via ldap authentication using vault, the vault based on role assigned to user gives us the policy ? I have created the token but how do I use it?

Comment: exactly what you said. To use the new token with the policy you need, you can either export it as env var `VAULT_TOKEN` or provided it via the headers if you are using the API